# GWT Exception: SimplePanel can only contain one child widget

Tags: java, gwt, frontend

The following ui.xml file output throws a exception

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="uiPanelDialog" styleName="{CSS.common.flexContainerColumn} {style.content}">
    <g:Label ui:field="uiLabelTitle" styleName="{style.title}" text="What are you Looking for?"/>
    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="uiPanelOptions" styleName="{style.scroll}">
        <g:FocusPanel ui:field="uiPanelWelcomeTutorial" styleName="{style.options}">
            <g:Image styleName="{style.image}" url="res/images/user_b.png" width="60px" height="60px" />
            <g:Label>Welcome Tutorial</g:Label>
        </g:FocusPanel>
        <g:FocusPanel ui:field="uiPanelGettingStarted" styleName="{style.options}">
            <g:Image styleName="{style.image}" url="res/images/user_b.png" width="60px" height="60px" />
            <g:Label>Getting Started</g:Label>
        </g:FocusPanel>
        <g:FocusPanel ui:field="uiPanelAppointmentManagement" styleName="{style.options}">
            <g:Image styleName="{style.image}" url="res/images/user_b.png" width="60px" height="60px" />
            <g:Label>Appointment Management</g:Label>
        </g:FocusPanel>
        <g:FocusPanel ui:field="uiPanelClientMangement" styleName="{style.options}">
            <g:Image styleName="{style.image}" url="res/images/user_b.png" width="60px" height="60px" />
            <g:Label>Client Mangement</g:Label>
        </g:FocusPanel>
        <g:FocusPanel ui:field="uiPanelStaffManagement" styleName="{style.options}">
            <g:Image styleName="{style.image}" url="res/images/user_b.png" width="60px" height="60px" />
            <g:Label>Staff Management</g:Label>
        </g:FocusPanel>
        <g:FocusPanel ui:field="uiPanelIntegrationSetup" styleName="{style.options}">
            <g:Image styleName="{style.image}" url="res/images/user_b.png" width="60px" height="60px" />
            <g:Label>Integration Setup</g:Label>
        </g:FocusPanel>
        <g:FocusPanel ui:field="uiPanelTechnicalSetup" styleName="{style.options}">
            <g:Image styleName="{style.image}" url="res/images/user_b.png" width="60px" height="60px" />
            <g:Label>Technical Setup</g:Label>
        </g:FocusPanel>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="uiPanelFooter">
        <g:FocusPanel ui:field="uiPanelGetHelpOnline" styleName="{style.options}" width="50%">
            <g:Label>Get Help Online</g:Label>
        </g:FocusPanel>
        <div class="{style.option-divider}" />
        <g:FocusPanel ui:field="uiPanelSendFeedback" styleName="{style.options}" width="50%">
            <g:Label>Send Feedback</g:Label>
        </g:FocusPanel>
    </g:HTMLPanel>

</g:HTMLPanel>
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SimplePanel can only contain one child widget

I am not able to figure out why it is giving this exception.What is the problem in the above code. I want to learn how I can I put different section in focus panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>    <g:FocusPanel ui:field="uiPanelWelcomeTutorial" styleName="{style.options}">
>        <g:Image styleName="{style.image}" url="res/images/user_b.png" width="60px" height="60px" />
>        <g:Label>Welcome Tutorial</g:Label>
>    </g:FocusPanel>
> ```

`FocusPanel` extends `SimplePanel`, which can only have one child, as your error tells you. I'm not sure why you are using `FocusPanel` to wrap these two children, but you cannot do this - only one child in there is allowed. If you want them to be collectively focusable for some reason, put both `Image` and `Label` in a container together, and put *that* into the `FocusPanel`.